How to Resolve 'ytmusicapi: command not found' Error on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.6.9
I need to generate an oauth.json for the ytmusicapi library using the ytmusicapi oauth command. I installed the ytmusicapi library with pip install ytmusicapi and ran $ ytmusicapi oauth in the Ubuntu terminal.
All I get is this error:

ytmusicapi: command not found


Python 3.6.9
Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

How to fix this error?

Could you share which version of ytmusicapi is installed on your machine after running pip install ytmusicapi? You can check it with pip show ytmusicapi  command.

ar@gro:~$ pip install ytmusicapi
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: ytmusicapi in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.22 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ytmusicapi) (2.25.1)

It seems like you don't work in properly isolated environment and you have multiple versions of Python and ytmusicapi available (in question you mentioned that you use Python 3.6, while comment content suggests that you also have Python 3.10). Make sure that you use newer version of Python and ytmusicapi, as I recommended in my answer. Also, make sure that ~/.local/bin is on your PATH, as that's where your ytmusicapi executable should be available.

As you work with Python 3.6, pip installs version of ytmusicapi which is compatible with Python 3.6. On ytmusicapi's repository, you can see that Python 3.6 support was ditched since 0.24 version.
On the other hand, CLI that you are trying to use was introduced in 1.0.0 release of ytmusicapi. Therefore it can't be available in your setup.
You have two possible solutions for your problem:

(recommended) Upgrade Python on your machine and use latest version of ytmusicapi along with CLI for OAuth authentication you tried to use (with latest Python pip install ytmusicapi command should install latest version automatically).
If you really can't upgrade Python (you should, as 3.6 version is not supported anymore), you can try to work with older version of ytmusicapi which you have already installed. Luckily, there is documentation for older versions of library available, so check which version you have installed (you should likely work with 0.22 or 0.23) and read documentation about authentication for this specific version - here is the link for 0.22 version. Keep in mind though, that OAuth support was added in 1.0 release, so you will have to use browser headers authentication.

